# Add another row in pandas dataframe based on a condition on the date column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe :

```
ID           Date          col3         col4
1           25/08/2021     Manual       NA
1           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA
1           27/08/2021     Manual       NA          <----- Insert another row after this row based on max date condition for ID 1
2           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA
2           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA          <----- Insert another row after this row based on max date condition for ID 2
```

For each ID, I want to insert a row after the row with the maximum date. Inserted row should have values from the row with maximum date for first 3 columns but for col4, it should have values as "ADDED". So my output df will be :

```
ID           Date          col3         col4
1           25/08/2021     Manual       NA
1           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA
1           27/08/2021     Manual       NA               
1           27/08/2021     Manual       Added            <-------- Inserted row
2           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA
2           27/08/2021     Automatic    NA
2           27/08/2021     Automatic    Added            <-------- Inserted row
```

In above example, for ID : 1 , I inserted another row after row number 3 as it is the row with maximum date. Column values for this inserted row is same as of the row with maximum date. col4 is however changed to "Added"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the extra rows using:

```
df.sort_values(by='Date').groupby('ID').last().assign(col4='Added')
```

*NB. If the dates are already sorted, you can remove the sorting step*

Then you just need to concatenate them with the original data:

```
pd.concat([df,
           df.sort_values(by='Date').groupby('ID').last().assign(col4='Added')
           ]).sort_values(by='ID')
```